# SAPUI5 pendingChanges get lost

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

i am working on an SAPUI5 App with odata-services. 
To avoid the loss of changes in case of an error while updating an EntitySet i have a function call before.
This functionCall calls the same code as the update method of the entity but without commit.
In the success-Method of the function call i call the submitChanges-Method.
This works fine but now i have a problem with some fields.
I change two fields and found the changes in the model (oModel.getPendingChanges).
After the call of the functionCall some changes get lost. In this case one of the changes gets lost and the other one is still visible in the model.
Here is my save-method:

```
    onSavePressed: function() {
            if (this.getView().getModel().hasPendingChanges()) {
                var oChanges = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                oChanges.setData(this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/" + this.sPath));


                this.getView().getModel().callFunction("/CheckData", {
                    method: "GET",
                    urlParameters: {
                        param1: oChanges.oData.param1,
                        param2: oChanges.oData.param2,
                        param3: oChanges.oData.param3,
                        param4: oChanges.oData.param4
                    },
                    success: function(oData, response) {
                        this.getView().getModel().submitChanges({
                            success: function(oData, oResponse) {                                   
                                sap.m.MessageToast.show(this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("DATA_SAVED"));
                            }.bind(this),
                            error: function(oError) {
                                console.log(oError);
                            }.bind(this)
                        });
                    }.bind(this),
                    error: function(oError) {
                        console.log(oError);
                    }.bind(this)
                });
            }

        },
```

Do you have an idea why this changes get lost or how to avoid the loss of this changes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason for the Problem.
Just should have read the documentation for callFunction:
*If the return type of the function import is either an entity type or a collection of an entity type, then the changes are reflected in the model*